# WTelegramClient giving FILE_PART_X_MISSING error when sending image

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, wtelegramclient

I am using WTelegramClient library for making client for Telegram messenger.

My goal is to send message with image every one hour to selected group.
When I leave computer untouched the code gives this error:

> TL.RpcException: 400 FILE_PART_X_MISSING,

but if I use my PC while code running it won't give any errors. Could it be a problem related to Windows 11, where certain operations or file accesses may be paused or slowed down to conserve power or resources?
Here's my code:

```
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats();
var messageImage = await client.UploadFileAsync(@"C:\...\image.jpg");

while (true) {
    await client.SendMediaAsync(chats.chats[my_group_id], "Text for the message", messageImage);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); /* I need message to be send every 1 hour */
}
```

I also tried sending a message without an image, and that worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your uploaded image got deleted server-side somehow (especially if it's spam your sending)

I don't think it's related to your PC activity.
If possible you may edit your question to add some [WTC logs](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/EXAMPLES#logging), it would help to analyze the problem.

As a workaround, you can try to reupload the image when this error happens.